# How to send property values to svg files using ember-inline-svg?

Tags: svg, ember.js, handlebars.js, inline-svg

I am using ember-inline-svg, there is a logo.svg file, I'm calling it with

`{{inline-svg 'logo' class="logo" }}`

in my hbs file.

It works fine. I just need to send one more data param to it and access that in the svg file so that I can dynamically generate svgs. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: how do you want to use that params inside the svg file? if you want full handlebars features it's no longer a svg file. then just use a normal component and put your svg stuff inside. this will *just work as expeted*.

Comment: @Lux I would just like to change the value of the title tag inside that file accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want is not possible, because `svg` itself has no dynamic parts.

however you probably don't need `ember-inline-svg` at all. Could it be a possibility to put your svg inline into a component?

Just create a component `Logo` and put the `svg` inside the `logo.hbs`:

```
<svg height="60" width="200" ...attributes>
  <text y=20 >I love {{@name}}</text>
</svg>
```

Then set `tagName: ''` (or use a [template-only-glimmer-component](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0278-template-only-components.md)). Then you can just use it as a component:

```
<Logo class="logo" @name="Ember" />
```

Comment: I know. but have to use ember-inline-svg. so trying to find a hack.

Comment: Why? Please elaborate.

Comment: project guidelines and stuff. anyway, I managed to make an exception for this svg. Thanks for your help.

Comment: then theese guidelines are stupid. I see usefulness inside `inline-svg` for lazy loading `svg`s or loading external `svg`s. However never make things more complicated then necessary.